# for loops instead of if else statement

Tags: if-statement, for-loop

program: 
what else can I use in this program instead of using multiple if else statement

my desire number is until a thousand.

```
 do {
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            if(a==1)
                System.out.println(o[0]);     
            if(a==2)
                System.out.println(o[1]);  
            if(a==3)
                System.out.println(o[2]);  
            if(a==4)
                System.out.println(o[3]);  
            if(a==5)
                System.out.println(o[4]);
            if(a==6)
                System.out.println(o[5]);
    }  
while(a!=0);
     if (a==0){
     System.out.println("You entered number zero");

    }
```

Comment: No loop needed, merely a subtraction.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because think about it a little yourself please. Also there is no programming language tagged, so this is clearly not about a programming language (:laffo:)

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    if (a != 0 && a < o.length) {
        System.out.println(o[a-1]);
    }
} while(a != 0);

if (a == 0) {
    System.out.println("You entered number zero");
}
```

Comment: +1 but you can add the description of what change you have done :)

Comment: -1 from me until you do. Code dumps without explanation are actually harmful.

Comment: thanks for answering I got the idea hehe

Answer (score 1):

Start by analyzing the pattern: given `if(a==X) System.out.println(o[Y]);`, what is the relation of `X` (and therefor `a`) to `Y`?

Now eliminate all the if-else statements to take this into account - the program should be left with a single `System.out.println(o[..]);` line (where the expression `..` transforms `a` by the pattern identified above).

Then, what is the domain of `X` (and `a` by extension)? That is, for what values of X should this `println` operation occur?

Add an if statement *around* the above `println`; this will prevent output when the user enters 0 (or 7), for instance.